# How can we open .xls or .xlsx file in browser?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

The requirement is to open xls or xlsx in browser directly with out downloading, I could able to do this with word documents.

Is there any open source or commercial dll's or plug-ins which support this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati

Comment: I have already tried that one. it's not working

Comment: For clarification.  Do you want to depend on the end-user having Excel installed on their machine? Or do you want to display in the data in spreadsheet like control from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be Office Online : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-online-help/get-started-at-office-com-HA101785172.aspx

There are two versions, the cloud one that you can try for free on OneDrive and that is also provided by Sharepoint Online as part of Office 365, or the on premisses one that you can get by licensing Office Web Apps Server.

These are in my opinion the best experience you can get to view AND modify word or excel files in a browser.

As for embedding them in you MVC application, you can use the following documentation by Microsoft : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/embed-an-excel-spreadsheet-on-a-web-page-FX102602477.aspx

Basically the office web app provides you the markup needed for embedding a given document, a simple iframe.

The "hard" part will be transferring your documents into the office web app, but that depends on the implementation you pick up.